# How do I install the Django snippet dumpscript?

Tags: linux, django

How do I install a Django snippet, in particular [snippet 818](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/818/) - `dumpscript`, on Linux?

**Update 2**. The question was about Linux, but for reference I have listed the corresponding way to install `dumpscript` on Windows below, e.g. for use during development. (But it can also be done the other/standard way if there are no file access restrictions.)

**Update 1**. This will install it for an application named "programRelease" (in a Linux command-line window, [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) shell):

```
cd /home/msquant/www/GoogleCodeHost/programRelease
mkdir management
touch management/__init__.py
mkdir management/commands
touch management/commands/__init__.py
wget  http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/818/download/ --output-document=/home/msquant/818.py
cp /home/msquant/818.py management/commands/dumpscript.py
```

---

The snippet `dumpscript` is now part of [Django Custom Management Command Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) but I can't install it as this is on the hosting server where I have no rights to touch the Python installation. This is the error message when running "python setup.py install" to install the command extentions:

```
error: could not create '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_extensions': Permission denied
```

Instead I just want to install the snippet and use it.

I have tried to install it this way on the hosting server:

```
cd /home/msquant/
wget  http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/818/download/  --output-document=818.py
cp /home/msquant/818.py /home/msquant/www/GoogleCodeHost/dumpscript.py
```

And using it this way:

```
cd /home/msquant/www/GoogleCodeHost
python manage.py dumpscript programRelease
```

Error message:

```
Unknown command: 'dumpscript'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

The built-in `dumpdata` works (outputting in the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format):

```
cd /home/msquant/www/GoogleCodeHost
python manage.py dumpdata programRelease
```

---

Ref "Update 2" above:

To install on Windows (assumes EXE file `wget` lives in directory D:\wget, and that the temporary directory, d:\temp2, exists):

```
d:
cd D:\dproj\MSQall\website\GoogleCodeHost
mkdir management
echo. > management\__init__.py
mkdir management\commands
echo. > management\commands\__init__.py
D:\wget\wget.exe  http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/818/download/ --output-document=d:\temp2\818.py
copy d:\temp2\818.py management\commands\dumpscript.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the snippet in `{appname}/management/commands/`, where `{appname}` is the name of an installed app. Each Python module in that directory will be auto-discovered and registered as a command that can be executed as an action when you run `manage.py`.

You'll need to put an empty `__init__.py` in both `{appname}/management/` and `{appname}/management/commands/` for this to work, if those files don't already exist.

See [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) for more on writing custom commands (obviously in your case, the command is already written).

Comment: It worked with the management/commands directories after creating an empty "__init__.py" in each of the two directories. Thanks!. I have updated the question with the final solution.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen - thanks, forgot that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't updated that djangosnippets version for a while, I hope it works for you.

Note that, you don't need to "install" pure python apps like `django_extensions`; you can use it by just putting the folder on your path somewhere (like where you project's directory is). Failing that, try and use the `dumpscript.py` file found in `django_extensions` (it's newer)

I should have some time in the next few weeks to develop `dumpscript` a little further and get it to play better with some of the newer django features :-)

Cheers, Will

Comment: dumpscript works fine. E.g. I used it today for a database migration (because the Django models in my application were extended).